# Не могу считать текстовый файл, вместо русских сиволов пишет вопросики

Tags: java

Пишу программу на Java, которая считывает текстовый файл побайтово и отправляет серверу, сервер принимает побайтово и конвертирует в текст, выводя на консоль.
Но на этапе считывания файла он не может писать русские символы. Знаю, что проблема в кодировке, но уже всю голову сломал, не знаю куда копать. Кто может с этим подсказать?)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сервер принимает и выводит на консоль... а эта консоль понимает кодировку от сервера? Я смотрю ты на Windows, там своя кодировка в консоли может быть.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить кодировку в настройках на `UTF-8`.

Comment: Может быть это пригодится: http://microsin.net/adminstuff/windows/bad-encoding-symbols-in-windows-console.html , https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/chcp.html

Comment: Я менял колировку в ide)

Answer (score 1):

Да, проблема в кодировке, когда читаешь поток байтов и конвертируешь в строку(текст) надо явно задавать кодировку и тоже самое при отправке. Если не задавать явно, то используется кодировка по дефолту.

Пример:

```
String test = "Тест Тест Hello World! @";
InputStream stream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

while(reader.ready()){
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
}
```